# Which is correct in this instance - "meaning that I got" or "meant that I got"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

> "I was seven time zones away meaning that I got few disturbances."
>   **or**
>   "I was seven time zones away meant that I got few disturbances."

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

> "I was seven time zones away meaning that I got few disturbances."
>   **or**
>   "I was seven time zones away meant that I got few disturbances."

Neither seem completely correct, but I believe the intended meaning is:

> "I was seven time zones away, **which meant** that I got few disturbances.

Other ways of rendering it could be:

> "**Being** seven time zones away **meant** that I got few disturbances."
>   "I was seven time zones away **and so** I got few disturbances."

Answer (score 0):

Your first is fine (though I'd put a comma before *meaning*). The second doesn't make sense.

The first is equivalent to *which means/meant that*. (I put the present or past there because the participle *meaning* is neutral as to tense, so in general it could be either. But I agree with Astralbee that the past *which meant that* is more natural there.)

The second would be equivalent to *which is/was meant that*, because the so-called past participle *meant* is inherently passive, so if you expand it to a full clause you need the passive form *is/was meant*. But *which was meant that I got few disturbances* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The word to use here is "meaning," not "meant."

If you were to write this as two sentences, you'd write:

> I was seven time zones away. That meant that I got few disturbances.

But how do you combine these two sentences into one? Since "that" is the subject of the sentence, you need to use the *active participle*. The active participle of "to mean" is "meaning." (The active participle is also called the present participle, but this is misleading.) So the combined sentence is:

> I was seven time zones away, **meaning** that I got few disturbances.

The passive participle (also called the past participle) is used when you're talking about the *object* of an action. For example, consider these two sentences:

> I walked into the kitchen and saw my husband **baking** some cookies.
>
> I looked inside the cookie jar and saw some cookies **baked** by my husband.

In both of these sentences, we use a participle in order to say that my husband baked the cookies. In the first sentence, we use "baking" (the active participle) because my husband is the *subject* of the sentence "my husband baked the cookies." In the second sentence, we use "baked" (the passive participle) because the cookies are the *object* of the sentence "my husband baked the cookies."